# Why is the negative binomial distribution the sum of r geometric distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

Does anyone understand why the negative binomial distribution is the sum of r geometric distributions? See the example given below. Could someone please explain the logic behind this statement and perhaps give a simple example?

[image]

Comment: If it surprises you that negative binomial distribution corresponds with sum of iid geometrics then you must have some conception of the negative binomial distribution already. What is your conception?

Comment: There are various ways to define the negative binomial distribution. This is one of them. I you take this as the definition then the 'why' question is pretty meaningless, 'negative binomial' is then just the, admittedly weird, name given to the sum of geometrics. However if you have a different definition of the negative binomial distribution in mind then the why question is perfectly valid. In that case: can you type the definition you are using into your question?

Answer (score 1):

a geometric distribution counts the trials to get the first success...

think you have r independent geometric distributions...each rv counts how many trials you need to get the first (one) success.

It is very intuitive to realize that the sum of these r rv's count the number of trials to get r successes....this is a negative binomial

a different parametrization of geometric distribution (counting the failures before the first success) generates a sum that is a Pascal distribution

[Here](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture16.pdf) you can find all the details duly explained